# Is it possible to access vue instance in axios interceptors?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using vue-reactive-storage since localStorage is not reactive. Usage of this plugin creates a vue object accessible to all components. I want to access this object within my axios interceptors response function but I get the common `TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined`.

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import reactiveStorage from "vue-reactive-storage";
import store from './store/index';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(reactiveStorage, {
  "snackBar": {show: false, text: '(Initial snackbar text.)', type: 'info', timedelay: 2000},
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
    this.localStorage.snackBar.text = error.response.data.message || 'Request error status: ' + error.response.status,
    this.localStorage.snackBar.type = 'error'
    this.localStorage.snackBar.show = 'true'
})

import router from './routes';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    router,
    store,
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

Laravel v6.4.1, Vue v2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Vuex store? it is reactive. And you could add a plugin for your interceptor like this:

```
export default function ({ $axios, store, redirect, context }) {
    $axios.onResponse(response => {
    // your code
    store.commit('set_sample_data', response.data)
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and is explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Real-World-Example-Replacing-Vue-Resource-with-Axios).

TL;DR: Use an old fashioned function definition and set it to the prototype, to let this function gain your Vue instance's context binding.